# mongoose lookup (join) and project only last one

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregate lookup command:

```
aggregate.lookup({
    from: 'phonecalls',
    localField: 'phone',
    foreignField: 'to',
    as: 'phonecalls'
});
```

I want to only get the last 'phonecall' I made (by a date field).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
aggregate([
    { $lookup: {
          from: 'phonecalls',
          localField: 'phone',
          foreignField: 'to',
          as: 'phonecalls'
       }
    },
    { $unwind:"$phonecalls", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }, 
    { $sort:{ "phonecalls.date":-1 } }, 
    { $limit:1 }, 
    { $project:{ lastphonecall: "$phonecalls" } }
]);
```

Comment: This is not working. This makes a limit 1 for the whole aggregate. I want to get all the items I find, and do the limit only for the phonecalls, not for the containing query.